# Auto Replies going back to Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid

We are using sendgrid to send emails via SMTP. Sendgrid attached the return-path header to the outgoing emails so that bounces go back into sendgrid. However if a user has vacation emails set up they are being returned to the return-path. Do we have any way of capturing the emails somehow in Sendgrid? It appears the web hooks for bounces do not capture the auto replies and they do not appear anywhere.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem, did you ever find a solution for this?